# Typescript changing the output directory structure to include src

Tags: typescript, rollup

The Typescript compiler seems to randomly change the structure of the output directory which throws off linked dependants.

Where it used to be

```
+- dist
  +- index.d.ts
  +- index.js
```

It suddenly changed to

```
+- dist
  +- src
    +- index.d.ts
  +- index.js
```

(I know the answer I'm just signposting for my forgetful future self - been through this twice already!)

Answer (score 1):

I'd added a `test-utils` folder to the project root and it contained modules that were referenced by test modules under `src` and so tsc changed the directory structure to accomodate.

Check you're not referencing modules at the top level by accident